# Devise and Rails - ArgumentError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When a new user submits a new user registration form they get the below error message. I suspect it because the devise/registrations_controller.rb doesn't exist.

Do I need to create this folder structure and controller or can I modify the routes.rb to avoid searching for a non-existent controller?

Error:

```
 ArgumentError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

 wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
 Rails.root: C:/Users/COMPAQ/Documents/NetBeansProjects/RailsBlog

 Parameters:

 {"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/c=",
  "user"=>{"email"=>"foo@bar.com",
  "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
  "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
  "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

routes.rb:

```
RailsBlog::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
```

User.rb (model):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password

  #has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
  #has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  #has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed

  #has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
           #class_name:  "Relationship",
           #dependent:   :destroy
  #has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save :create_remember_token

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
            format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

  def feed
    Micropost.from_users_followed_by(self)
  end

  def following?(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id)
  end

  def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id).destroy
  end

  private

  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

end
```

Trace back - I have had a look but cannot determine where issue lies:

```
devise (2.1.2) lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:109:in `password_digest'
activemodel (3.2.1) lib/active_model/errors.rb:254:in `block in add_on_blank'
activemodel (3.2.1) lib/active_model/errors.rb:253:in `each'
activemodel (3.2.1) lib/active_model/errors.rb:253:in `add_on_blank'
activemodel (3.2.1) lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb:9:in `validate'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:310:in `_callback_before_185'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:484:in `_run__875543711__validate__219075599__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activemodel (3.2.1) lib/active_model/validations.rb:212:in `run_validations!'
activemodel (3.2.1) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `block in run_validations!'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__875543711__validation__219075599__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
activemodel (3.2.1) lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `run_validations!'
activemodel (3.2.1) lib/active_model/validations.rb:179:in `valid?'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/validations.rb:69:in `valid?'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/validations.rb:77:in `perform_validations'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:190:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:241:in `block in save'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:252:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:240:in `save'
devise (2.1.2) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:15:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__853675117__process_action__862668662__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:40:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__805649291__call__219075599__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
C:/RUBY/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RUBY/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RUBY/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in  start_thread'
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `Devise::RegistrationsController` exists [within the Devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/tree/master/app/controllers/devise), so you don't need to create it.

**Update**:
The error occurs because you are using `has_secure_password`, which is for homemade authentication solutions. You don't need it with Devise (it handles the encryption of the password itself). Get rid of that line!

The reason it causes your app to blow up is that it expects `password_digest` to be an attribute on your model, and [validates its presence](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L43). When it does the validation, it tries to read the attribute, but what it gets instead is Devise's `password_digest` method (which expects to receive the password as an argument, so raises an `ArgumentError` when it doesn't get one).

Comment: Added trace info and user model to question. How did you determine issue?

Comment: The 5th line of the backtrace was the clue that it was validations: `lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb:9:in 'validate'`. The 1st line shows the method that was being called incorrectly (`password_digest`).

Comment: Perfect. Saved my day! +1