# Migrate from existing password_digest column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, bcrypt

I have a custom `User` model with lots of rows. I have a `password_digest` column that I want to keep. (it comes from `has_secure_password`)

And I also want to use Devise database authenticatable, but from my limited knowledge on Devise, I have to use the encrypted_password column.

Is there a way to trick Devise into using my current `password_digest` for authentication, so I don't lose all my User passwords?
If I add an `encrypted_password` column it will be blank and I definitely don't want it to stay like that.

I'm probably thinking about this the wrong way. What's the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply write a migration to rename the column name, it will not loose your data.

```
 rails g migration ChangeColumnName
```

this will generate a migration file

```
class ChangeColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
       rename_column :users, :password_digest, :encrypted_password
    end
end
```

Comment: Interesting, but now I get `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
from /home/aantonov/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:144:in `password_digest'`. I am lost in Devise

Comment: Seems you are using `has_secure_password` for this reason  it expects `password_digest` and causing error. Better read from this post  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715627/devise-and-rails-argumenterror-in-deviseregistrationscontrollercreate)

Comment: Gave it a day to sink in and it works. Had to refactor a bit of other methods that relied on password_digest but it's all working now. Big thanks Rokibul Hasan!